# Facing issue while modifying open messaging to test the custom standalone installation of Pulsar

Tags: apache-pulsar

Can we modify open-messaging benchmark tool(https://github.com/openmessaging/benchmark) to load test the standalone Apache instance

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean?
Of you want to use it for local development you can just that Apache Pulsar Standalone locally and launch locally the benchmark.

Just change the namespace to public/default in the .yaml file in driver-pulsar.

By the way running locally is not very useful, as for real testing you need:

- the client running on separate machines
- a cluster installation with replicates data
- multiple client machines

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any modifications. The benchmark will run in single-node mode if you don't pass a list of worker nodes. Just point to any Pulsar cluster or standalone instance.